# Best practices for Filtering CoreData records via UiControls

Tags: ios, core-data, uibutton, nspredicate

Im building an app where users will be able to filter through a set of photos based on 4 parameters:

[model http://seismicdevelopment.com/shot.png](http://seismicdevelopment.com/shot.png)

FeedType and PhotoType can be one of three possible values respectively. Market and Tag can contain multiple values that describe the photo. I have the ui setup where for FeedType/PhotoType is a series of UISwitches for each param. If you turn one value on, the others in that group will turn off.

Market/Tag have UIButtons that can be made selected/normal.  Any selected button should be added to the filtering to narrow results.

I can't seem to figure out how I should write the filtering logic to be most effective. Essentially on any control change, I need to rewrite the predicate filter but I can't seem to wrap my head around how I can link the separate param filters together.

For Tag/Market I'd also like to add a disabled state for UIButtons that have no records, or no records based on the currently selected buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell a precise advice without knowing what kind the parameters are, but, as far as i can see, you need to have four variables,more likely,NSStrings, and every time the user changes the parameter, you create a new fetch predicate, by appending all that variables with the right format. That's how i see it in general.

## UPDATE

So, with Market and Tag Butons everything is quite obvious - you shoud use `NSCompondPredicate`. You'll need an array of predicates, so make a property.

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *subpredicates;
```

Then, each time user touches the button, you add or remove that narrowing predicate.

```
- (void)tagButtonTouched:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (thisTagIsNotYetSelected)
        [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.name == %@", button.titleLabel.text]];//or some other predicate based on that button title
    else
        [subpredicates removeObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.name == %@",button.titleLabel.text] ]];
}
```

Same thing for `Markets`

```
 - (void)marketButtonTouched:(UIButton *)button
 {
     if (thisMarketIsNotYetSelected)
         [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY markets.name == %@", button.titleLabel.text]];//or some other predicate based on that button title
     else
         [subpredicates removeObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY markets.name == %@",button.titleLabel.text] ]];
 }
```

You should also add two variables,i guess,`NSPredicates` or `NSString`,that will hold the value of selected `FeedType` and `PhotoType`,lets's call them `feedTypePredicate` and `photoTypePredicate` respectivly. When user touches those switches(why not segmentedControls?), you just change their's values.

And, finally, you should just combine all those predicates into one and make your fetch!

```
if(photoTypePredicate)
    [subpredicates addObject:photoTypePredicate];
if(feedTypePredicate)
    [subpredicates addObject:feedTypePredicate];
NSPredicate *finished = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];//Your final predicate
```

Comment: Thank you. I added an image of the CoreData model and the values that I'm using. I thought keeping it generic might be simpler.

Comment: Updated my answer to make it more complete

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but this doesn't appear to work.  I implemented this code and my results for Photo never change. I have 108 entires and I'm always getting 108 back. Is there possibly a property that I can set to ensure the predicate is evaluated for ALL of the values in the predicates and not an ANY-type operation? Thats the only reason that I could imagine where the same results come back.

Comment: Just an additional note, I'm able to run each type of predicate on its own successfully. I had to add quotes for the market.name/tag.name values. So it just seems like the compounding is where the problem is.

Comment: My apologies. The array of subpredicates was NULL because of an oversight on my end. Thanks again for the solution. After going through this troubleshooting I realize how easy this really was. I was jus taking it too hard on myself :)